# Is there a way to test jsr223 assertion in result tree of jmeter (for e.g we can test Regular expression in result tree)

Tags: jmeter, assertion, jsr223

Current I am using jsr223 assertion in jmeter for functional testing of API. So I need to test my assertion on response message in result tree , such that we don't need to run the call every time. ( For e.g we can test regular expression in result tree).
So Is there any way to test jsr223 assertion against the response message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per current JMeter version (3.1) it something not possible, however the workaround exists.

You can use [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) to mimic your test data so you won't have to re-run the whole scenario in order to validate a single assertion.

[image: JMeter Dummy Sampler]

You can install Dummy Sampler (as well as any other JMeter Plugin) via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[[image: JMeter Plugins Manager - Dummy Sampler]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T for the response it worked for me, but I need to disable all the calls , then I have to add the response in jp@gc sampler and attach a jsr223 assertion then run it again and again.
Is there any way to add jsr223 assertion in result tree??

Answer (score 0):

[prev.getResponseMessage()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseMessage()) - gives HTTP response message

`prev.getResponseDataAsString()` - gives the complete response as a string.

Try as follows in `JSR223 Assertion`:

```
log.info(prev.getResponseMessage());
String response = prev.getResponseMessage();
if(response.contains("OK")){
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("response message contains OK");
}
```

You have access to following things in `JSR223 Assertion`:

1. [Response](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)- using `prev` or `SampleResult`
2. [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) - you can tweak the assertion result based on some conditions.